# Youtube iframe embed, weird playlist showing at the end

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm inserting a youtube video on my website.

I customized everything I could so it wouldn't look like a youtube embed. And made it loop.

Now this weird playlist thing is appearing once the video loops.

How to remove it?

**Iframe code:**

```
<iframe width="426" height="319" 
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/hhLt3p01phg?&autoplay=1
&rel=0
&fs=0
&theme=light
&loop=1
&showinfo=0
&disablekb=1
&controls=
0&autohide=1
&playlist=hhLt3p01phg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try removing the playlist parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for reference.

What you need is:

The video url: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z8GHf-aELjY

The embedded video url: http://www.youtube.com/embed/z8GHf-aELjY

**Note**: The above url is taken from the demonstrated website.

Now, update the `iframe src` attibute with to the following:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/z8GHf-aELjY?rel=0&showinfo=0"
        frameborder="0"
        allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Notice how I added the `rel=0&showinfo=0` at the end of the `src` attribute of the `iframe` element.

From the [YouTube API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters):

> *rel*: This parameter indicates whether the player should show related
>   videos when playback of the initial video ends. Supported values are 0
>   and 1. The default value is 1.

And for

> *showinfo*: Supported values are 0 and 1.
>
> Setting the parameter's value to 0 causes the player to not display
>   information like the video title and uploader before the video starts
>   playing.
>
> If the player is loading a playlist, and you explicitly set the
>   parameter value to 1, then, upon loading, the player will also display
>   thumbnail images for the videos in the playlist. Note that this
>   functionality is only supported for the AS3 player.

The demonstration can be found at [this website](http://illuminea.com/remove-related-videos-from-end-of-embedded-youtube-video/)

Answer (score 1):

It' just a bug in the player.  I've reported the issue to the development team, but until it's fix you could try using the chromeless player.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference#GettingStarted

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However this bug dissapeared for me somehow a long time ago